# Creating LINQ query with two parameters

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

I am new to LINQ and I feel some difficulties to write that LINQ query.

I need to write LINQ TO ENTITY to check if table named `Reviews` where all rows with `siteId=5` has at least one row with column named `isValid` that equal `false` if there is, I need to return false if not return true.

Comment: Give it a try at-least. Hint: Use `Any`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a Filter with SiteId

```
IEnumerable<Review> FilteredReviews = Reviews.Where(x=>x.SiteId == 5)
```

Check whether any value of `IsValid is False`, return accordingly

```
return FilteredReviews.Any(y=>!y.IsValid) ? false : true
```